# Is there a name for the property of a function f such that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

As in the title: is there a name for the property of a function such that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

I don't know how to be clearer than that. I tried to look for symmetric property on Google, but without any luck. Thank you!

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function)

Comment: Thank you. So let's say that we have f(a,b,x,y)=f(a,b,y,x) but NOT equal to f(b,a,x,y) or any other permutation on a and b,  would be correct to say that the function is symmetric with respect of y and x?

Comment: @Vaal Yes, why not. But the first time you use that terminology, define it properly just to be clear what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function such that $f(x,y) =  f(y, x)$ is called a ***[symmetric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function).***

Comment: sorry, I just realized I forgot to check this as accepted answer. I did now. Thank you very much!