# Is there a term for a function being "invariant under permutations of the parameters"?

Tags: terminology

Suppose we have a function $f:X^n\to S$. And suppose we know that $f$ has the property that it is invariant under permuting the parametera. E.g. if $n=2$, then $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for any $x,y$.

Is there a name for this property?

Comment: I remember terms like cyclic or symmetric, but if $S=X$, and you intend $f$ to be a 'fundamental' operation, then "abelian" or "commutative" should work.

Comment: Related (but only covering $n=2$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899113/is-there-a-name-for-the-property-of-a-function-f-such-that-fx-y-fy-x

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric function is a commonly used name for this property.
The wikipedia page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_mathematics).